# filter nested json on multiple values

Tags: javascript

I have JSON with some data and key **results**. The results can have multiple objects in it. Every object has its status, and I'm filtering this data for it. If something is found like I'm filtering for "pass", the function returns the whole parent object with key results but objects in there that don't have the correct status are removed

**example**

```js
let test_data = {
    "test_name": "test1",
    "plan": "asasas",
    "country": "some country",
    "date_created": "2023-07-10T10:55:42.253000",
    "date_last_updated": "2023-07-10T10:55:42.253000",
    "owner": {
      "RowID": "G_6",
      "TaskName": "Like a G6",
      "Freq": "474.0"
    },
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "PASS",
        "date_created": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "date_created": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614"
      }
    ]
}

function filterByStatus(status_word) {
    
  let filtered_data = [test_data].map((element) => {
      return {
        ...element,
        results: element.results.filter((results) =>
        results.status.toLowerCase().includes(status_word)
        ),
      };
  });
    console.log(filtered_data)
}

filterByStatus('failed')
```

this works fine but how to make it work when the **status_word** is an array with multiple values like

```
['pass', 'failed']
```

so that I can get pass *or* failed or send a request for pass **and** failed.

Note that statuses can be different than that so the values can't be hardcoded in.

Comment: `status_word.includes(results.status.toLowerCase())` ? i.e check if the status lowercase is included in the status_word array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the filtering section:

```js
results: element.results.filter((results) =>
    status_word.some(x=> results.status.toLowerCase().includes(x))
),
```

```js
let test_data = {
    "test_name": "test1",
    "plan": "asasas",
    "country": "some country",
    "date_created": "2023-07-10T10:55:42.253000",
    "date_last_updated": "2023-07-10T10:55:42.253000",
    "owner": {
      "RowID": "G_6",
      "TaskName": "Like a G6",
      "Freq": "474.0"
    },
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "PASS",
        "date_created": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "date_created": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614"
      }
    ]
}

function filterByStatus(status_word) {
    
  let filtered_data = [test_data].map((element) => {
      return {
        ...element,
        results: element.results.filter((results) =>
        status_word.some(x=> results.status.toLowerCase().includes(x))
        ),
      };
  });
    console.log(filtered_data)
}

filterByStatus(['pass', 'failed'])
```

If you want to accept both string and array filtering use this:

```js
results: element.results.filter((results) =>
    [status_word].flat(1).some(x=> results.status.toLowerCase().includes(x))
),
```

Now, both `filterByStatus('pass')` and `filterByStatus(['pass', 'failed'])` work as expected.